# Flask Form Post data to another html page

Tags: python, flask

I have a form that gets data and redirects to the bk.html page. I want to get the results from submitted form and have the page redirect with that info on it. I can dynamically put it on the same page but I don't know how to add it to a new page.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect
app = Flask(__name__)
# our index route will handle rendering our form
@app.route('/')
def index():
  return render_template("index.html")

@app.route('/users', methods=['POST'])
def create_user():
   print "Got Post Info"
   name = request.form['name']
   DojoLocation = request.form['location']
   FavoriteLanguage = request.form['Language']
   textarea = request.form['textarea']
   # redirects back to the '/' route
   return render_template('bk.html')

app.run(debug=True) # run our server
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Dojo Survey Index</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/my_style_sheet.css')}}">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/my_script.js')}}"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id = container 1 >
<form action='/users' method='post'>
Name: <input type='text' name='name'>
Dojo Location:  <select name="location">
<option value="Silicon Valley">Silicon Valley</option>
<option value="Seattle">Seattle</option>
<option value="Los Angeles">Los Angeles</option>
<option value="Dallas">Dallas</option>
<option value="Washington DC">Washington DC</option>
<option value="Dallas">Dallas</option>
<option value="Chicago">Chicago</option>
<option value="Berkely">Berkely</option>
<option value="Orange County">Orange County</option></select>
Favorite Language:  <select name="Language">
<option value="ios swift">ios swift</option>
<option value="Ruby on rails">ruby on rails</option>
<option value="Python">Python</option>
<option value="Mean">Mean</option>
<option value="C# ">C# DC</option>
</select>
<textarea name="textarea" value = "textbox" rows="4" cols="50" name="comment" ></textarea>

<input type='submit' value='submit'>
</form>
</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you trying to have the form data used on the `bk.html` page? If so you might want to use a template and have template variables inside of `bk.html` that will reference the form data you pass the template via `render_template` -

Comment: Yea im trying  to post the info on the bk page

Answer (score 2):

When you return the render_template() function, you can add the variables as:

```
var1 = 'this is a test string'
return render_template("bk.html", var1 = var1)
```

In your bk.html file, include the following to show the variable where you want it shown.

```
{{ var1 }}
```

You can read more on http://jinja.pocoo.org/